# How to remove extension from the filenames from a list of filenames in Python?

Tags: python, string, csv, for-loop

I am trying to rename all the items in the list by removing the '.csv' extension from each item

The following code removes the extension in the variable **new** but does not replace **each** with **new**:

```
csv = ['NC_hello1.csv', 'NC_hell02001.csv', 'NC_hello20002.csv']
for each in csv:
     new = os.path.splitext(each)[0]
     each = new
     print each
```

How do I get the following output?

```
NC_hello1
NC_hell02001
NC_hello20002
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
csv = [os.path.splitext(each)[0] for each in csv]
```

Alternatively, if you need to further process the modified filename, e.g. print it like in the code above, access the list by indexing its elements:

```
for index,each in enumerate(csv):
    new = os.path.splitext(each)[0]
    csv[index] = new
    print new
```